# rebuild Column using markNeedsBuild not working

Tags: flutter

Flutter: rebuild Column using markNeedsBuild not working.

```
List<String> names = [];
int i = 0;
GlobalKey key1 = GlobalKey();

Column(children: [
   Column(
      key: key1,
      children: List<Widget>.generate(names.length, (index) => Text(names[index]))
   );

   IconButton(onPressed: () {
       names.add('Name ${i++}');
       (key1.currentContext as Element).markNeedsBuild();
      },
      Icon: Icon(Icons.add),
   ),
  ]
);
```

Clicking button to add a new name, then refresh the column to show the new name list.

No error or exception, but the name list is not refreshed.

Comment: Why don't you use the commonly used approach, that is to use `setState` inside a `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: need to add two more classes for statefulWidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey _globalKey = GlobalKey();
  final List<String> _names = [];
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ColumnWidget(key: _globalKey, names: _names),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _names.add('Name ${_counter++}');
                
                (_globalKey.currentContext as StatelessElement)
                    .markNeedsBuild();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColumnWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColumnWidget({required this.names, super.key});
  final List<String> names;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List<Widget>.generate(names.length, (i) => Text(names[i])),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: using StatelessWidget works.